# How to check if a row is a subset of a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say we have this data.frame `df`

```
uid | aid | Freq
-----------------
 2  |  4  |  3
 9  |  1  |  2
```

How do we check if this row `r <- data.frame(uid=9, aid=1)` is in `df`

For vectors >> we use `%in%` but it didn't work here.

Comment: You can check with `merge(df, r)`

Comment: One idea: `any(duplicated(rbind(unique(df[names(r)]), r)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with `merge`. Just be sure that column names match:

```
df <- head(mtcars)
r <- data.frame(mpg=18.1, cyl=6)
mrg <- merge(df, r)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

There are many ways you can turn this into a logical test.

```
nrow(mrg) > 0
```

Comment: so putting it in a condition form would be `if_else((merge(df, r) %>% nrow()) > 0, T, F)`

Comment: @mabdrabo - Or `nrow(merge(df, r)) > 0`

Comment: @RichScriven, yes of course. It's just because I was going to add upon it. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @RichScriven

Comment: I might suggest approaching the problem without using merge: just select by row value: `any(r$uid == 9 & aid == 1)`.