# Check if data.frame is a subset of another data.frame

Tags: r, join, merge, string-matching

Let's assume I have the following lookup table:

```r
(lkp <- structure(list(a = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c"),
                       b = c("a1 a2", "a3 a2", "a3", "a1", "a1")), 
                       row.names = c("lkp_1", "lkp_2", "lkp_3", "lkp_4", "lkp_5"), 
                       class = "data.frame"))
#       a     b
# lkp_1 a a1 a2
# lkp_2 a a3 a2
# lkp_3 a    a3
# lkp_4 b    a1
# lkp_5 c    a1
```

I want to check if another `data.frame`, `x`, say,  is a subset of `lkp`, with the important additional requirement, that for column `b` matching means that `lkp$b` need only to **contain** `x$b`.

The following example should make clear what I mean:

```r
(chk <- list(c1 = structure(list(a = c("a", "a"), b = c("a2", "a2")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
             c2 = structure(list(a = "b", b = "a1"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
             c3 = structure(list(a = c("a", "a"), b = c("a1", "a1")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
             c4 = structure(list(a = c("a", "a"), b = c("a3", "a2")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")))

# $c1
#   a  b
# 1 a a2
# 2 a a2

# $c2
#   a  b
# 1 b a1

# $c3
#   a  b
# 1 a a1
# 2 a a1

# $c4
#   a  b
# 1 a a3
# 2 a a2
```

- `chk$c1`: row 1 matches row `lkp_1` (and `lkp_2`) as column `a` is the same and `lkp$b` contains `a2`
- `chk$c2` and `chk$c4` match as well
- `chk$c3` does **NOT** match. While each row matches `lkp_1`, `c4` is not a subset as `lkp` would  need to contain **2 different** rows which match.

In principle I am looking for a merge (or join)  where the join condition would use some sort of fuzzy matching.

I have found and read these two SO answers:

- [How to check if a row is a subset of a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872901/how-to-check-if-a-row-is-a-subset-of-a-data-frame)
- [R merge data frames, allow inexact ID matching (e.g. with additional characters 1234 matches ab1234 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165256/r-merge-data-frames-allow-inexact-id-matching-e-g-with-additional-characters)

And especially the second answer looks promising. However, I do not need approximate matching but rather some sort of `does_contain` relationship instead of pure equality. So maybe a `regex` solution would work?

### Expected Outcome

```
magic_is_subset_function <- function(chk, lkp) {
   # ...
}
sapply(chk, magic_is_subset_function, lkp = lkp)
# [1] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment,I added the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(
    chk,
    function(v) {
        sum(
            rowSums(sapply(v$a, `==`, lkp$a) &
                sapply(v$b, grepl, x = lkp$b)) > 0
        ) >= nrow(v)
    }
)
```

or

```
sapply(
    chk,
    function(v) {
        sum(
            colSums(
                do.call(
                    `&`,
                    Map(
                        function(x, y) outer(x, y, FUN = Vectorize(function(a, b) grepl(a, b))),
                        v,
                        lkp
                    )
                )
            ) > 0
        ) >= nrow(v)
    }
)
```

which gives

```
   c1    c2    c3    c4 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Nice idea, but  does not work in case `lkp` contains more matching rows: (think of `lkp <- rbind(lkp, lkp[4, ])`). Any ideas?

Comment: What's the expected output with your new `lkp`?

Comment: Same ad before `TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE`. BTW: `c4` evaluates to `FALSE` in your case. it shoudl return `TRUE`.

Comment: @thothal Why it should be `TRUE`?

Comment: `a a3` matches `lkp_3` and `a a2` matches both `lkp_1` and `lkp_2` (one match would be already sufficient). Rule is: first column must match as is, second column must  be contained.

Comment: @thothal Okay, I see. You can use `>=nrow(v)`, rather than `==`.